# Find the second largest and smallest number in a list

Tags: list, scheme

Write a Scheme function that takes a simple list of numbers as its parameter and returns the second largest and second smallest numbers in the list. The returned values should be in a list as (smallest largest)
Note that if
needed, you can define other auxiliary functions which the minmax function can call in its body.

(DEFINE (minmax list)

(

body

)
)

```
(define (mintwo lst)
    (cond ((null? (cdr lst)) (car lst))
          ((< (car lst) (mintwo (cdr lst))) (car lst))
          (else (mintwo (cdr lst)))) )

(define (maxtwo lst)
    (cond ((null? (cdr lst)) (car lst))
          ((> (car lst) (maxtwo (cdr lst))) (cdr lst))
          (else (maxtwo (cdr lst)))) )
```

these functions I have for max and min but the funny part is that when I input this

(maxtwo'(3 4 2 9 3 8))

I get the error which is correct

expects a real as 2nd argument, given (list 3 8)

the error is the third row in the maxtwo function

Now how can I make a function to call those 2 mintwo and maxtwo function and as an output is the second smallest and second largest number both in a list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't say I confidently understand your problem statement, but the `maxtwo` function you use doesn't find the second-greatest element of a list; it finds the greatest. Same for `mintwo`.

An algorithm for finding the second-greatest element of an array in C:

```c
int snd_maximum(int arr [], int size) {
   int max = * arr++;
   int snd = * arr++;
   size -= 2;

   int n;

   if (snd > max) {
      n = max;
      max = snd;
      snd = n;
   }

   while (size --) {
      n = * arr++;

      if (n > max) {
         snd = max;
         max = n;
      }
      else if (n > snd) {
         snd = n;
      }
   }

   return snd;
}
```

The collection must have ≥ 2 elements. A rough translation:

```scm
(define (snd-max xs)
   (define (trav max snd xs)
      (if (null? xs)
         snd
         (let ((x (car xs)))
            (if (> x max)
               (trav x max (cdr xs))
               (if (> x snd)
                  (trav max x (cdr xs))
                  (trav max snd (cdr xs)) )))))
   (let ((x (car xs))
         (x' (cadr xs)) )
      (if (> x x')
         (trav x x' (cddr xs))
         (trav x' x (cddr xs)) )))
```

The searches for second-greatest and -least can be combined into a single traversal of the collection, returning a tuple of the two results.

In general, to find the n-greatest element of a collection, that collection has to be freed of duplicate elements, and sorted. Then an ordinal (naturals from 1) lookup delivers. To find the nth-greatest element, the collection must have ≥ n unique elements.